# Is there any method of reading non-standard table use organizing labels without loop?

Tags: r, xml

As far as we know, the parsing library like XML and xml2 can read standard table on web page perfectly. But there are some sorts of table which has no grid of table but organizing labels, such as `“<span>”` and `“<div>”`.
Now I am coping with a table like this, 
The structure of table marks with `“<span>”`, and every 4 `“<span>”` Labels organize one record. I’ve used a loop to solve this problem and succeed. But I want to process it without loop. I heard that library purrr may help on this problem, but I don’t know how to use it in this situation.
I do my analysis by both “XML” and “xml2”:

1. Analysis with “XML” package

> ```
> pg<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/simple-search?fq=eperson.unique.id%3A311007%5C-000920"
> library(XML)
> tableNodes <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(pg), "//table[@class='miscTable2']")
> itemlines <- xpathApply(tableNodes[[1]], "//tr[@class='itemLine']/td[@width='750']")
> ispan <- xmlElementsByTagName(itemlines[[2]], "span")
>   title <- xmlValue(ispan$span)
>   isuedate <- xmlValue(ispan$span[1,2])
>   author <- xmlValue(ispan$span[3])
> ```

In this case, “XML” got a list of one span, but this list is very strange but met my expectations:

```
> attributes(ispan)
$names
[1] "span" "span" "span" "span"
```

It seems have one row only, but four columns. However, it doesn’t. The 2-4 “span” couldn’t be select by column. The first “span” occupied 2 columns, and other “span” could not get.

```
> val <- xmlValue(ispan$span[[1]])
> val
[1] "超高周疲劳裂纹萌生与初始扩展的特征尺度"
> isuedate <- xmlValue(ispan$span[[2]])
> isuedate
[1] "  \r\n                  [科普文章]"
> isuedate <- xmlValue(ispan$span[[3]])
> isuedate
[1] NA
> author <- xmlValue(ispan$span[[4]])
> author
[1] NA
None of the selection method used in list works:
> title <- xmlValue(ispan$span[1,1])
```

> Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
>         no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalNodeList', 'XMLNodeList')"

`title <- xmlValue(ispan$span[1,])`

> Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
>         no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalNodeList', 'XMLNodeList')"
>   author <- xmlValue(ispan[1,3])
>       Error in ispan[1, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions

2. Analysis with “xml2”

Use “xml2” the obstacle of “span” makes same problem

```
pg<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/simple-search?fq=eperson.unique.id%3A311007%5C-000920"
library(xml2)
tableSource <- xml_find_all(read_html(pg, encoding = "UTF-8"), "//table[@class='miscTable2']")
itemspan <- xml_child(itemspantab, "span")
```

It could not gether any of these “span” labels:

```
> itemspan
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <NA>
```

If we make a step further to locate the “span” labels, it only get nothing:

```
> itemspanl <- xml_find_all(itemspantab, '//tr[@class="itemLine"]/td/span')
> itemspan <- xml_child(itemspanl, "span")
> itemspan
{xml_nodeset (40)}
 [1] <NA>
 [2] <NA>
 [3] <NA>
...
```

An suggest told me use library(purrr) to do this, but the “purrr” process dataframe only, the “list” prepared by “xml2” could not be analyzed.
I want not to use loop and get the result like below, can we do it? I hope the scholars who have experience on “XML” and “xml2” could give me some advise on how to cope with this non-standard table. Thanks a lot.
[image: the ideal result extract from webpage and organized by loop]